# MYSql container not getting set up using docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a simple container with [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) docker image. I am able to run the container and set it up using command prompt as below

```
docker run --name test-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="myrootpassoword" -d mysql
```

But when I try to do it using docker-compose, the container gets up but I am not able to connect to mysql db using `mysql -p`. My password is not working, it keeps getting access denied and I am not able to work with the container. Below is my compose file. Am I missing anything?

```
# Docker Compose file Reference (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)



version: '3'

# Define services

services:
  # Mysql Service

  db:
    image: "mysql" # Use a public mysql image to build the mysql service 
    volumes: 
      - dbvol:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "myrootpassowrd"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "mydb"
      MYSQL_USER: "myadmin"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "mypassword"

    ports:
      - "3306:3306" # Forward the exposed port 3306 on the container to port 3306 on the host machine
    container_name: test-mysql


volumes:

  dbvol:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue causing this trouble. My password contained $ symbol which is used to get variable in docker, so the next character/part was considered as variable and as value was not set, it was taken as blank without actually throwing any error.

To escape it I had to use two dollar signs `$$`
So I modified the code from

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "myroot$passowrd"
```

to

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "myroot$$passowrd"
```

and it worked properly.